# Reducing independent set to clique?

Tags: graph, np

Show that given a graph G and a number k, there is some way to transform it to a graph H such that G has an independent set of size of size at least k if and only if H has a clique of size at least k.

Answer (score 5):

An independent set is a group of nodes where for any pair of nodes in the set, there is *not* an edge between those nodes. A clique is a group of nodes where for any pair of nodes in the set, there *is* an edge between those nodes. Therefore, an independent set in a graph G is a clique in the [complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph) of G and vice-versa.

Given this, a simple transformation would be given G and k to produce G<sup>c</sup> (the complement of G) and k. Then, G has an independent set of size k if and only if G<sup>c</sup> has a clique of size k.

Hope this helps!